# Iterate over different lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, python-itertools

I'm trying to itterate over 2 different lists in python and after this itteration I want to get new list, which will include new data.

I have a code:

```py
import itertools
current_week = [42,43,44,45,46]
late_pcs = [10,27]
late_week = [45,46]

late_list = []
for week, pcs in itertools.zip_longest(current_week, late_pcs):
    if week not in late_week:
        late_list.extend([0])
    else:
        late_list.extend([pcs])
```

I need to compare 2 lists. If number from list "current_week" is in "late_week" I need to take number from list "late_pcs".

We're taking number 42 and starting to check if this number is in "late_week". If it's False - we add 0 to "late_list" and so on. If it's True - we add number from "late_pcs".

As a result I need to get new list like this:

```py
late_list = [0, 0, 0, 10, 27]
```

But I am getting:

```py
[0, 0, 0, None, None]
```

I know I can use **fillvalue** for **zip_longest**, but I don't think that it could be useful for we in this way.
Maybe I choiced wrong way to get a right result.

Comment: What would be the output if `late_week = [45, 43]`?

Comment: Actually late_week = [45, 46]. Or what this list should include so?

Comment: Are you avoiding dictionaries on purpose?

Comment: What I meant to ask is whether numbers in `late_pcs` are taken based on the position of the matching number in `late_week`, or simply based on list order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution without importing from `itertools`:

```
current_week = [42,43,44,45,46]
late_pcs = [10,27]
late_week = [45,46]

late_list = []
for week in current_week:
    if week in late_week:
        late_list.append(late_pcs.pop(0))
    else:
        late_list.append(0)

print(late_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a counter to keep the trace. You do not need to use `zip_lingest()`:

Each time to append an element from `late_pcs`, you increment the counter `c`

```
current_week = [42,43,44,45,46]
late_pcs = [10,27]
late_week = [45,46]
late_list = []
c = 0                       # counter variable
for week in current_week:
    if week not in late_week:
        late_list.append(0)
    else:
        if c<len(late_pcs):    # if condition to make sure index dont overlow
            late_list.append(late_pcs[c])
            c+=1
```

---

```
print(late_list)
[0, 0, 0, 10, 27]
```

Comment: `if late_pcs[c]:    # if condition to check whether the index c exists or not` That is not how you check if an index exists or not.

Comment: @blhsing thanks.. you are right! I have edited. Please see.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good place to use `iter`.

The advantages of using `iter` instead of `pop` are that the original list is unchanged. Also `pop(0)` results in every remaining item in the list being moved for each pop. This could causes a performance issue when you are using `pop(0)` with long lists.

```
result = []
fill_value = iter(late_pcs)
for week in current_week:
    if week in late_week:
        result.append(next(fill_value))
    else:
        result.append(0)
print(result)
```

You can simplify a little with a ternary if/else

```
result = []
fill_value = iter(late_pcs)
for week in current_week:
    result.append(next(fill_value) if week in late_week else 0)
print(result)
```

And even write it as a list comprehension

```
fill_value = iter(late_pcs)
result = [next(fill_value) if week in late_week else 0 for week in current_week]
print(result)
```